# Looking for NTU-HD dataset (a hand gesture dataset)

Tags: data-request, images

I'm looking for the NTU-HD dataset (a hand gesture dataset; each gesture consists of a color image and the corresponding depth map).

The reference article is [Robust hand gesture recognition based on finger-earth mover's distance with a commodity depth camera](http://eeeweba.ntu.edu.sg/computervision/people/home/renzhou/Ren_Yuan_Zhang_MM11short.pdf).

NTU = Nanyang Technical University, Singapore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Hand Gesture Recognition](http://eeeweba.ntu.edu.sg/computervision/people/home/renzhou/HandGesture.htm) at Nanyang Technical University, Singapore:

> We have collected a 10-gesture hand gesture dataset with Kinect sensor which contains both color images and depth maps. Our dataset is collected under cluttered background, which includes 10 subjects × 10 gestures/subject × 10 cases/gesture = 1000 cases. Download [here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B_9saHAqGFITODNmNzU0ZjctMjk0Yi00YjI5LWJmZDMtYTdiYTE2YzM5OTQ4&hl=en_US).
>   (Please cite the papers to use the dataset)

**Hint** Found by googling *Robust hand gesture recognition based on finger-earth mover's distance with a commodity depth camera site:ntu.edu.sg*